# Webserver on Arduino: How to 307 temporary redirect

Tags: arduino-uno, ethernet

I originally asked this [question.](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/28124/webserver-on-arduino-refresh-issues?newreg=fec67955f67e4baea0fc7402e8cb57da) Regarding a webserver Refresh issue on arduino.

I am totally new to web development and ethernet. The answer from @Majenko is correct, but I do not understand how to implement it. Should I change the `homepage()` function's first line to `HTTP/1.1 307 temporary redirect` and use `META REFRESH`?

Or do the `homepage()` first using `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` and then for all the following requests, use `HTTP/1.1 307 temporary redirect`?

Comment: @Majenko I would like you to answer this please.

Comment: This might be of use to you: http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a decision on what to respond with depending on what the request is you have received.

If you receive a "command" URL (which you already check for by looking for certain sub-strings) then you need to respond with the `307` response. If you don't receive a "command" URL (so anything *except* the things you are specifically looking for) then you respond with the homepage.

A slight re-formatting of your decision code to use `else if` instead of just `if` would make it easier:

```
if (c == '\n') {
  Serial.println(readString); //print to serial monitor for debuging
  // homepage(); << This is now moved elsewhere.
  //controls the Arduino if you press the buttons
  if (readString.indexOf("?resetcount1") > 0) {
    count1 = 0;
    redirect();
  } else if (readString.indexOf("?resetcount2") > 0) {
    count2 = 0;
    redirect();
  } else if (readString.indexOf("?resetcount3") > 0) {
    count3 = 0;
    redirect();
  } else if (readString.indexOf("?resetcount4") > 0) {
    count4 = 0;
    redirect();
  } else if (readString.indexOf("?togglerelay1") > 0) {
    toggleRelay1();
    redirect();
  } else if (readString.indexOf("?togglerelay2") > 0) {
    toggleRelay2();
    redirect();
  } else if (readString.indexOf("?togglerelay3") > 0) {
    toggleRelay3();
    redirect();
  } else if (readString.indexOf("?togglerelay4") > 0) {
    toggleRelay4();
    redirect();
  } else { // If none of them match then send the homepage.
    homepage();
  }
}
```

`redirect()` is as simple as:

```
void redirect() {
  client.println("HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect");
  client.println("Location: /");
  client.println("Connection: Close");
  client.println();
  client.stop();
}
```